# Lua interpreter works inconsistently with break statement

Tags: lua

Hi i am trying to learn Lua, I was playing around with the language and I come accrosed this code block

```
for i = 1, 4, 1
do
    if(i == 2) then
        break
        undefinedFunction("print 1")
    end

    
    print("print 2")
end
```

which is fine for the interpreter and did nothing for the undefined function. On the other hand if we make this code block like that

```
for i = 1, 4, 1
do
    if(i == 2) then
        break
        1
    end

    
    print("Hello World asdasdsad asdasdas")
end
```

which the lua interpreter throws error unexpected sign '1'.

So i thought that Lua interpreter fines with undefined functions and just ignore them but if i code like that

```
for i = 1, 4, 1
do
    if(i == 2) then
        break
        
    end

    undefinedFunction("argument 1")
    
    print("print 1")
end
```

now Lua interpreter gives error. Why there is an inconsistency?

Comment: it's the difference between "I can't read this program" and "I can read it, but it breaks when I run it"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference here is "syntax error" vs "runtime error".

The second snippet has a syntax error: A single literal (such as a number `1` or a string `"foo"`) is not a valid statement.
A file needs to be free of syntax errors before Lua can even begin to run it, which is why the second snippet will fail regardless of where you put the line with the `1`.

The third snippet has a runtime error: The file syntax is perfectly fine and Lua can start interpreting it. Only when it reaches the offending line will the VM realize that `undefinedFunction == nil` and that it can't use that as a function.

Contrast to the first snippet, where:

- there is no syntax error
- the line with a runtime error is "hidden" behind a `break` and will never be reached, thereby never triggering the error

And the `break` is nothing special here, a simple `if` can show the same behaviour:

Syntax error:

```lua
if true then
  1
end
```

Runtime error:

```lua
if true then
  undefined()
end
```

No error:

```lua
if false then
  undefined() -- This line is never reached, and will not cause an error
end
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all: Let's clean your code up a bit.

```lua
for i = 1, 4 do
    if i == 2 then
        break
        undefinedFunction("print 1")
    end
    print("print 2")
end
```

This code is **not fine in Lua 5.1**: In Lua 5.1, `break` must be the last statement in a block - that is, writing "dead code" after a `break` is syntactically not allowed and raises a **syntax error**. With the introduction of a powerful `goto`, later Lua versions started allowing code after a `break` as it may be alive if a `goto` is used.

Still, the call to `undefinedFunction("print 1")` is never executed, and as such never gets to throw a **run-time error**.

Now let's take a look at your second snippet, again cleaned up:

```lua
for i = 1, 4 do
    if i == 2 then
        break
        1
    end
    print("print 2")
end
```

This throws a **syntax error** because **the number `1` is an expression, not a statement**. `break` is a statement. A block is a list of statements. Lua expects either the `end` of the block or another statement, you give it an expression - **syntax error**.

Now to the third snippet:

```lua
for i = 1, 4 do
    if i == 2 then
        break
    end
    undefinedFunction("argument 1")
    print("print 2")
end
```

throws a **runtime error** because the **global variable** `undefinedFunction` - the same as `_G["undefinedFunction"]` is undefined (`nil`) - and you are **trying to call a `nil` value**.